# how to make an object that the value is coming form user input

Tags: javascript, user-input

```
var person {
  name; age; height;
};
```

that's the object and the properties. how do I input a value with user input using prompt box and external file js

Comment: @Snel23 how I validate that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example taking input from text input fields:

```js
var person = {
  name:"", 
  age:"",
  height:""
};


document.getElementById("get_person").addEventListener("click", () => {
  person.name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  person.age = document.getElementById("age").value;
  person.height = document.getElementById("height").value;
  
  console.log(person);
  
});
```

```html
<input id="name" type="text" value="name"></input>
<input id="age" type="text" value="age"></input>
<input id="height" type="text" value="height"></input>
<button id="get_person">Go</button>
```

Edit: Here is an example using the prompt box:

```js
var person = {
  name:"", 
  age:"",
  height:""
};


person.name = prompt("Please enter your name");
person.age =prompt("Please enter your age");
person.height = prompt("Please enter your height");

console.log(person);
```

Comment: var person = {
  name:"", 
  age:"",
  height:"",
};


person.name = prompt("Please enter your name");
person.age =prompt("Please enter your age");
person.height = prompt("Please enter your height");

document.write(name);
document.write(age);
document.write(height);

console.log(person);

Comment: why the input is null

Comment: Because you are writing `name` to the document, not `person.name` (for all variables)